# insert foreign key record asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add product detail for ever product sales and unable to reference sales id out of the controller created how to use foreign key to reference sales id from sales to sales detail

```cs
public ActionResult mainsales(int id = 0) 
{
    using(model db = new model()) 
    {
        dto1 = new Sale();
        int salesnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["salesnumber"]);
        dto1.SalesNumber = salesnumber;
        db.Sales.Add(dto1);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}

public ActionResult addsales(int id = 0) 
{
    long rfid = (long) Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["rfid"]);

    Category_Item_File item;
    using(model db = new model()) 
    {

        Category_Item_File dto = db.Category_Item_File.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Item_RFID == rfid);
        SalesDetail saledet = new SalesDetail();

        saledet.Item_Name = dto.Item_Name;
        saledet.SalesPrice = dto.Item_Price;

        saledet.SalesId = dto1.Id;

        db.SalesDetails.Add(saledet);
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (dto == null) 
        {
        }
        item = new Category_Item_File(dto);

        return View("Till");
    }
}
```

Comment: In both methods you are passing in an Id, but it is never used. Also as a general rule, your controller methods are doing too much. All the repository stuff you are doing here, should be in a repository layer. You should think of the controllers as just that, a switching mechanism for passing data down to the service layer and up to the views

Comment: When you call mainsales method and save the sales records. after save sale model you get salesId. Store that sales id in tempData or viewbag and  get that id in addsales method.

Comment: thanks A.M. Patel for help but i want the functionality so that i can add as many sales detail as needed how can i do that?